# How to make the activation of function keys permanent in Arch

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux

Searching I found [THIS question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121395/on-an-apple-keyboard-under-linux-how-do-i-make-the-function-keys-work-without-t) that explains how to activate function keys, only the changes don't seem to be permanent.

at each startup the content of the file `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` returns to **3**.

Why **3**? aren't the allowed parameters just in the range **0-2**?

How can I make changes to the `/sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode` file permanent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why 3? aren't the allowed parameters just in the range 0-2?

No, option `3` was added in 2022 for Linux 5.18, while the documentation you're reading seems to have been last updated in ~2012.

```
$ modinfo hid-apple
parm:           fnmode:Mode of fn key on Apple keyboards (0 = disabled,
                1 = fkeyslast, 2 = fkeysfirst, [3] = auto) (uint)
```

> How can I make changes to the /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode file permanent?

It's a module parameter, so you can configure it a) through modprobe or b) kernel command line.

- When modules are loaded via modprobe, their parameters are read from files in `/etc/modprobe.d` (see the `man modprobe.d` manual page):

  ```
  options hid-apple fnmode=2
  ```

  Don't forget to re-run `mkinitcpio -P` to have the file copied into the initramfs (as that's most likely when the module actually gets loaded).
- Default parameters can also be specified through the kernel command line (via GRUB or such):

  ```
  linux root=... rw hid_apple.fnmode=2
  ```

  (At least, I think that should work.)

Comment: In your answer you omitted to create a configuration file with `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/hid_apple.conf` and put `options hid-apple fnmode=2` inside. A not very experienced user might have some difficulty.

Comment: After some hesitation your answer worked! As soon as you update it, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1):

It's not the optimal solution, but for now I've done this:

1. **Creation of the systemd service file:** Use the `nano` text editor with superuser privileges to create a new systemd service file. The command to run is `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/fnmode.service.`
2. **Populating the service file:** The service file needs to be populated with the following systemd directives:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Set hid_apple fnmode

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo 2 > /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode'

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. **Enabling the systemd service:** The systemd service needs to be enabled for startup at system boot. This can be done with the command `sudo systemctl enable fnmode`.
4. **Starting the systemd service:** Finally, the systemd service can be started immediately without having to reboot the system. This can be done with the command `sudo systemctl start fnmode`.